# Error: Foreign key Constraint Violation. can't add/update a child row

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys, laravel-5

Can anyone help me ?? i am stuck in setting foreign key Constraint.
I am getting

```
 ERROR:foreign key constraint violation: Can't add/update a child row.
```

I am having a users,Projects,hours,tasks and sub-tasks table.
I have created migrations for tables in this order

```
 1.Users 2.Projects 3.Hours 4.Tasks 5.Sub-tasks
```

After these migrations, I created a new migration in which I added five new fields into hours table 3 fields for hours and two foreign keys from tasks and sub-tasks table i-e task_id and subtask_id.
i have already made foreign keys unsigned(), and these foreign keys are the same as in parent tables.

i have searched alot but most of replies says that you are creating child table before parent table or something like this.

**Hours Migration**

```
class CreateHoursTable extends Migration
{
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
      Schema::create('hours', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('actual_hours');
        $table->string('productive_hours');
        $table->integer('project_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('project_id')
         ->references('id')
         ->on('projects')
         ->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
   Schema::drop('hours');
}
}
```

**Tasks migration:**

```
class CreateTasksTable extends Migration
{
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('tasks', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');

        /* Relations Table Field Starts */
        $table->integer('project_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('project_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('projects')
            ->onDelete('cascade');

        /* Relations Table Field Ends */

        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('key');
        $table->text('description');

        $table->integer('percentDone');
        $table->date('duedate');
        $table->integer('reporter');
        $table->integer('follower');
        $table->string('tags');

        /*Task ENUM Fields Starts*/
        $table->enum('types', ['New Feature','Bug','Improvement','Task']);
        $table->enum('priority', ['Blocker','Minor','Major','Trivial','Critical']);
        $table->enum('workflow', ['Todo','In Progress','In QA','Completed']);
        $table->enum('component', ['Web','Android','IOS']);
        /*Task ENUM Fields Starts*/

        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('tasks');
}
}
```

**Sub-tasks Migration:**

```
class CreateSubtasksTable extends Migration
{
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('subtasks', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');

        /* Relations Table Field */
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('users')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->integer('task_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('task_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('tasks')
            ->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->string('name');
        $table->text('description');
        $table->integer('percentDone');
        $table->date('duedate');
        $table->string('reporter');
        $table->string('follower');
        $table->string('tags');
        $table->enum('priority', ['Blocker','Minor','Major','Trivial','Critical']);
        $table->enum('Workflow', ['Todo','In Progress','In QA','Completed']);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('subtasks');
}
}
```

**Migration To Add New Fields in Hours Table:**

```
class AlterTableHoursAddColumnsHours extends Migration
{
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('hours', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('estimated_hours');
        $table->integer('internal_hours');
        $table->integer('consumed_hours');
        /*Now Fields for Task And Subtask Tables Starts*/
        $table->integer('task_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('task_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('tasks')
            ->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->integer('subtask_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('subtask_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('subtasks')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
        /*Now Fields for Task And Subtask Tables Ends*/
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('hours', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropColumn('estimated_hours');
        $table->dropColumn('internal_hours');
        $table->dropColumn('consumed_hours');

        $table->dropForeign('hours_task_id_foreign');
        $table->dropColumn('task_id');

        $table->dropForeign('hours_subtask_id_foreign');
        $table->dropColumn('subtask_id');
    });
}
}
```

Is this because i created hours table before Tasks and Sub-tasks table. ??? Any Solution ?? Any Help ??

Comment: Just a tip: it should be better if you paste the code directly in the question as text. It is harder to read your question with the code as images.

Comment: Hi. Google that blah blah after removing your particular names. Do you think you are the first person to get this error message? Also read all the mentions for the key words in it in the manual, ie read about FK constraints. Also act on [mcve]. That includes minimizing your code, in fact here minimize it until the error stops then put the last cut back. And a spec, executable input, DDL & query and desired output. Also it includes [using text, not images/links, for text for text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097).

Comment: @Laerte and philipxy thanks for the tip. should i add code ??

Comment: @Laerte i have edited post. Do you see any mistake Now ??

Comment: When are you getting this error? When you're running the migration or attempting to add a row? If it's the latter, what are you trying to insert?